# RSpec Google Contacts Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

I'm trying to test out a controller action on Rails 2.3.10 that connect to Google to retrieve contacts.  I'm using Rspec and Mocha for testing.  I want to stub out the actual call to Google since this is a unit test.  I want to verify that the authsub_url method is called with the correct parameters.  Stubbing the method out causes the expectation to fail.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

My method that sets up the client to google is below:

```
  def setup_client
    @client = GData::Client::DocList.new(:authsub_scope => CONTACTS_SCOPE, :source => 'google-DocListManager-v1.1', :version => '3.0')    

    if params[:token].nil? && session[:google_token].nil?
      @authsub_link = @client.authsub_url(import_method_gmail_url, false, true)
      render :action => :index, :layout => "empty"
    elsif params[:token] && session[:google_token].nil?
      @client.authsub_token = params[:token]
      session[:google_token] = @client.auth_handler.upgrade
    end

    @client.authsub_token = session[:google_token] if session[:google_token]
  end
```

Here is my test:

```
  describe "setup_client" do
    it "has a authsub_link if there is no token parameter and the google token is not present in the session" do
      GData::Client::DocList.any_instance.stubs(:authsub_url).returns("http://test.google.com/contacts")
      user = Factory(:subscriber_user)
      profile = Factory(:profile, :user => user)
      login_as user

      controller.instance_variable_get(:@client).expects(:authsub_url).with(import_method_gmail_url, false, true).once

      get :index

      assigns(:authsub_link).should == "http://test.google.com/contacts"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [FakeWeb](http://rubygems.org/gems/fakeweb). It allows you to fake web requests. Simple define the URL you're going to call and prepare the response(s). Makes your life very easy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are stubbing out the `DocList#authsub_url` method in two places :-

The first stub is on any instance of `DocList` and returns a URL :-

```
GData::Client::DocList.any_instance.stubs(:authsub_url).returns("http://test.google.com/contacts")
```

The second stub is on the actual instance of `DocList` but this returns `nil` because no there is no `returns` clause :-

```
controller.instance_variable_get(:@client).expects(:authsub_url).with(import_method_gmail_url, false, true).once
```

I think you can achieve what you want by combining them something like this :-

```
controller.instance_variable_get(:@client).expects(:authsub_url).with(import_method_gmail_url, false, true).returns("http://test.google.com/contacts")
```

Note that `once` is the default so is not needed unless you want to emphasise that the method should only be called once.